# Python slice [:] inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

In Python why is the [:] slicing operation not consistent in its behavior?
It behaves differently for lists and strings.

For list it gives a copy list object, for strings it gives the same string object.

I find this confusing, counter-intuitive. Any way to explain/justify this?

```
    >>> s = "1234"
    >>> s is (s[:2] + s[2:])
    False
    >>> s is s[:]
    True
    >>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
    >>> lst is lst[:]
    False
    >>> lst is (lst[:2] + lst[2:])
    False
```

I find this part confusing. I would expect this to return `False`.

```
>>> s is s[:]
True
```

Also, I would expect these two to return the same result `False`, but that's not the case.

```
>>> s is (s[:2] + s[2:])
False
>>> s is s[:]
True
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, `interned` is not guaranteed in Python. Which means you cannot expect that the same strings point to the same one object.

Comment: @Sraw I am asking just the opposite.

Comment: If your program ever cares about the identity of immutable objects, you're probably doing something wrong. Object identity is important for mutable objects, but all sorts of object reuse optimizations are safe with immutables.

Comment: @user2357112 I see but... Well, the behavior still seems inconsistent. Why does `s is s[:]` return `True`. I find this strange, is it just me?

Comment: "not guaranteed" means, it may work, or not. It is not reliable. It is not a language feature. You don't need to ask about it. It is just because of different implementations. You may get totally diferent behaviors on `Jython` or `Pypy` or even different versions of `Cython`.

Comment: @peter.petrov that is an implementation detail, no doubt, a "whole slice" of a `str` object is optimized to simply return the `str` object itself. Why does this matter?

Comment: @Sraw OK... then how do I know what is guaranteed and what is not? Any official reference saying that this behavior is not defined/guaranteed?

Comment: @peter.petrov by reading the docs. Nowhere is it guaranteed that any string objects will be equal by identitiy (i.e. `is`). Why do you expect: `s is (s[:2] + s[2:])` to be `True`? Where does this assumption come from?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't expect that. Read my question again. I am expecting `s is s[:]` to return `False`.

Comment: @peter.petrov why do you expect them to "return the same result"? Where does that assumption come from?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Common sense, experience, consistency.

Comment: @peter.petrov I mean, I'm sorry, but that's really just handwaving. I can see that as true for *equality*, but what "common sense" makes you think those expressions will result in the same *identity* test?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I said several times already that I expect just the opposite.

Comment: What?? "Also, I would expect these two to return same result, but no." So you *do* expect them to result in the same identity test. Why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am expecting them both to return `False`. Please don't be so active with your comments. Spend some time to think first.

Comment: @peter.petrov **I am asking you why you expect them to both be False**. Why do you expect that consistency? In *my* experience, implementing operations that result in "return the same value of this immutable object" frequently just "return this immutable object"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I get that but then the operation becomes inconsistent between say strings and lists. And that's my whole point.

Comment: @peter.petrov right, but so? Many operations between lists and strings are inconsistent. They are very different data types, they just both happen to be *sequences*, in the parlance of Python.  So, for example, do you expect `+=` to be consistent between strings and lists? Because it isn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `+=` is quite consistent between lists and strings. Take it easy. I am just asking something here.

Comment: @peter.petrov it is certainly not. In `list` objects, it is a mutator method, and the object referred to by the name on the left-hand-side is mutated in place. With strings, a new object is returned and assigned to the name on the left-hand-side.

Comment: @peter.petrov anyway, consider this Java example: https://repl.it/@juanpa_arrivillaga/FrillyShrillJavadoc It seems Java's own equivalent method has the same optimization!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most built-in types, Python tries to ensure that (shallow) mutations of a slice don't affect the object the slice was sliced from.

For lists, this requires a copy, or mutating `l[:]` would mutate `l`.

For strings, strings don't support mutation, so statements like "mutating `s[:]` doesn't affect `s`" are vacuously true even if `s[:] is s`. There is no need to make a copy, so to save time and memory, the implementation doesn't make one. This is an implementation detail, not a language guarantee; it would be perfectly valid for the implementation to make a copy.

(You might think interning is involved, but it's not. This object reuse optimization is completely unrelated to interning. It happens even for non-interned strings. You can take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13986), if you want.)

---

In general, if your program ever cares about the identity of immutable objects, you're probably doing something wrong. Object identity matters for mutable objects, and Python makes sure to be predictable about the identity of mutable objects. For immutables, object identity matters very little, and Python applies a number of object reuse implementations that break many optimistic assumptions about object identity.

Answer (score 0):

Short strings are [interned](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/), so that a million instances of "test" don't take up a million strings' worth of storage. This is safe because Python's strings are immutable: if two strings are equal once, you can guarantee that they'll be equal for the rest of their lifetime.

Here's another example of short strings being represented by the same in-memory object:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'foo'
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: While interning is a thing, it's not involved here. (Also, length isn't actually involved in Python's interning criteria.)

Comment: How short? I just tried with a string of 200 characters and it still says that `a is a[:]` is `True`.

Comment: It's involved. `s[:]` is shorthand for "make a copy of s", which is most efficiently done with a pointer operation. `s[:2] + s[2:]` is different in that it's building a string up from pieces, and even though the result happens to already be in memory, it would be challenging for Python to determine that after-the-fact. I might be wrong about the string length bit though.